# Mimic Sharepoint edit Office file download

Tags: sharepoint

When you browse a list of files in Sharepoint using IE and attempt to download the file, you get the option of opening it in **read-only** or **edit** mode. When you open the document, Office knows that the file exists in Sharepoint so when you save, it is updated in Sharepoint without the user having to re-upload the file.

I'd like to have this same functionality in a custom website. I have access to Sharepoint and the file list so I'm using the same URL that Sharepoint is to download the file but there's something else happening in Sharepoint that tells the computer to not download a copy of the file but to open it in Office from the Sharepoint URL.

Does anyone know how to mimic this same behavior so I can get a file to be opened in Office from Sharepoint to it can save directly back to Sharepoint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The special thing about this, is the link:
It's not just `http://example.com/document.docx` . It's `ms-word:ofe|u|http://example.com/document.docx` .

Just add `ms-word:ofe|u|` in front of the link for letting the browser know to open the link with an other Application.
There are other strings for other links.

Open a OneNote-File with:

```
onenote:http://example.com/document.one
```

And Excel-Files with

```
ms-excel:ofv|u|http://example.com/document.xlsx
```

And just for fun a TeamSpeak Link:

```
ts3server://example.com
```

Comment: Awesome, do you know of a place that explains all of the different examples? Just wondering what the "ofe" and "u" parameters are.

Comment: Sorry, i found this out by using Google Chrome, which asked me how to open this link. But when i have to suggest, i would say **ofe** means something like **o**pen **f**ile **e**dit and the **u** stands for **u**ser

Comment: Just in case anyone else checks this out, look in your registry in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT for anything that starts with **ms-** and you'll see what all could be opened up by Office (word, excel, power point, visio, project, etc...) through a URL.

Comment: This has radically helped our shared document editing among our team. However, now we'd like to transition to MS Teams. Unfortunately, OneNote Web, and OneNote inside MS Teams appear to pre-pend "http://" in front of "ms-excel:ofe|...", and the links fail to work.

We have tons of OneNotes with literally hundreds of these style links to use with MS Teams. This bug is terrible. Does anyone have a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Create URL for MS Office 2010 (and higher) to:

- open document in view mode:

```
    ms-excel:ofv|u|http://server.com/path/filename.xlsx
```

- open document in edit mode:

```
   ms-excel:ofe|u|http://server.com/path/filename.xlsx
```

---

List of MS Office apps URL scheme names:

- ms-word:
- ms-powerpoint:
- ms-excel:
- ms-visio:
- ms-access:
- ms-project:
- ms-publisher:
- ms-spd:
- ms-infopath:

---

MS has a good page with explanation:

- MS Office Dev Center > [Office URI Schemes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn906146.aspx)